# prefix in json foursquare api

Tags: asp.net, json, api, foursquare

i have a json returned from foursquare api, here is a part of this json:

```
"categories": [
                {
                    "id": "4bf58dd8d48988d16e941735",
                    "name": "Fast Food Restaurant",
                    "pluralName": "Fast Food Restaurants",
                    "shortName": "Fast Food",
                    "icon": {
                        "prefix": "https://ss1.4sqi.net/img/categories_v2/food/fastfood_",
                        "suffix": ".png"
                    },
                    "primary": true
                }
            ]
```

how can i open the prefix and suffix to see the icon? when i open the link i'm getting an xml error...

any ideas?

Answer (score 2):

You try this 
https://foursquare.com/img/categories_v2/food/fastfood_64.png

because you must put this
 **prefix + size + suffix**,

Answer (score 1):

this https://foursquare.com/img/categories_v2/food/fastfood_64.png will not give you image 
you have to add _bg before size
 like https://foursquare.com/img/categories_v2/food/fastfood_bg_64.png

Answer (score 0):

See the [photo response docs](https://developer.foursquare.com/docs/responses/photo) on how to put `prefix` and `suffix` together. You need a size between them.

Comment: @JocelyneElKhoury what URL are you trying to use?